# updating and validating multiple files from different fields uploded with multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, upload, multer

I'm trying to update and validate a form consisting of two file inputs (one video and one image to be used as the video thumbnail) and two text inputs.
**the validator and convertFiletoField were working fine when I was uploading a single file however, they have both stopped working, this is a long question but, I appreciate it, if anyone can help.**

I'm using Node, epxress, mongodb and express-validator v.5.1.2

the Routes:

```js
router.get('/mvs', mvController.index);
router.get('/mvs/create', mvController.create);
router.post('/mvs/create',
    uploadVideo.fields([{
            name: 'videos', maxCount: 1
        }, {
            name: 'images', maxCount: 1
        }]),
    convertFileToField.videoHandle,
    mvValidator.handle(),
    mvController.store
);
router.get('/mvs/:id/edit', mvController.edit);
router.put('/mvs/:id',
    uploadVideo.fields([{
        name: 'videos', maxCount: 1
    }, {
        name: 'images', maxCount: 1
    }]),
    convertFileToField.videoHandle,
    mvValidator.handle(),    
    mvController.update
);
router.delete('/mvs/:id', mvController.destroy);
```

the Controller:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const controller = require('app/http/controllers/controller');
const Artist = require('app/models/artist');
const MV = require('app/models/mv');

class mvController extends controller {
    async index(req , res) {
        try {
            let page = req.query.page || 1;
            let mvs = await MV.paginate({} , { page , sort : { createdAt : 1 } , limit : 5 });
            res.render('admin/mvs/index',  { title : 'videos' , mvs });
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    }

    async create(req , res) {
        let artists = await Artist.find({});
        res.render('admin/mvs/create' , { artists });        
    }

    async store(req , res , next) {
        try {
            let status = await this.validationData(req);
            if(! status) {
                if(req.file) 
                    fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);
                return this.back(req,res);
            }
        
            // Create music video
            let videos = this.videoPath(req.files['videos'][0]);
            let images = this.videoPath(req.files['images'][0]);
            let { title, artist} = req.body;
            
            let newMV = new MV({
                title,
                slug : this.slug(title),
                artist,
                videos,
                images
            });
            await newMV.save();

            // update artist Times
            this.updateArtistTime(req.body.artist);

            return res.redirect('/admin/mvs');  
        } catch(err) {
            next(err);
        }
    }

    async edit(req, res ,next) {
        try {
            this.isMongoId(req.params.id);

            let mv = await MV.findById(req.params.id);
            let artists = await Artist.find({});
            if( ! mv ) this.error('video does not exist' , 404);
            return res.render('admin/mvs/edit' , { mv , artists });
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    }

    async update(req, res , next) {
        try {
            let status = await this.validationData(req);
            if(! status) {
                if(req.files) 
                    fs.unlinkSync(req.files.path);
                return this.back(req,res);
            }

            let objForUpdate = {};

            // check video 
            if(req.files) {
                objForUpdate.videos = this.videoPath(req.files['videos'][0]);
                objForUpdate.images = this.videoPath(req.files['images'][0]);
            }

            delete req.body.videos;
            delete req.body.images;
            
            objForUpdate.slug = this.slug(req.body.title);
            
            let mv = await MV.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id , { $set : { ...req.body, ...objForUpdate }});

            // prev artist time update
            this.updateArtistTime(mv.artist);
            // now artist time update
            this.updateArtistTime(req.body.artist);

            return res.redirect('/admin/mvs');
        } catch(err) {
            next(err);
        }

    }

    async destroy(req , res , next) {
        try {
            this.isMongoId(req.params.id);

            let mv = await MV.findById(req.params.id);
            if( ! mv ) this.error('video does not exist' , 404);


            let artistId = mv.artist;

            // delete music videos
            fs.unlinkSync(`./public${mv.videos}`);
            fs.unlinkSync(`./public${mv.images}`)
            mv.remove();

            // artist time update
            this.updateArtistTime(artistId);

            return res.redirect('/admin/mvs');
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    }

    async updateArtistTime(artistId) {
        let artist = await Artist.findById(artistId).populate('mvs').exec();
        artist.set({ time : this.getTime(artist.mvs)});
        await artist.save();
    }

    videoPath(video) {
        
        let addressVideos = this.getUrlVideo(`${video.destination}/${video.filename}`);

        return addressVideos;
    }

    getUrlVideo(dir) {
        return dir.substring(8);
    }

    slug(title) {
        return title.replace(/([^۰-۹آ-یa-z0-9]|-)+/g , "-")
    }
}

module.exports = new mvController();
```

the uploadVideo helper

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const fs = require('fs');

const getDirVideo = () => {
    let year = new Date().getFullYear();
    let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    let day = new Date().getDay();

    return `./public/uploads/mvs/${year}/${month}/${day}`;
}


const videoStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : (req , file , cb) => {
        let dir = getDirVideo();

        mkdirp(dir , (err) => cb(null , dir))
    },
    filename : (req , file , cb) => {
        let filePath = getDirVideo() + '/' + file.originalname;
        console.log(filePath);
        if(!fs.existsSync(filePath))
            cb(null , file.originalname);
        else
            cb(null , Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
            
    }
})

const uploadVideo = multer({
    storage : videoStorage,
    limits : {
        fileSize : 1024 * 1024 * 40
    }
});

module.exports = uploadVideo;
```

converFiletoField

```js
videoHandle(req , res , next) {
        if(! req.files) {
            req.body.videos = undefined;
            req.body.images = undefined;
        }
        else {
            req.body.videos = req.files.videos[0].filename;
            req.body.images = req.files.images[0].filename;
        }
            

        next();
    }
```

Validator:

```js
const validator = require('./validator');
const { check } = require('express-validator/check');
const Artist = require('app/models/artist');
const MV = require('app/models/mv');
const path = require('path');

class mvValidator extends validator {
    
    handle() {
        return [
            check('title')
                .isLength({ min : 3 })
                .withMessage('title can not be less than 3 characters'),
                

            check('artist')
                .not().isEmpty()
                .withMessage('related artist can not remain empty'),

            check('videos')
                .custom(async (value , { req }) => {
                    if(req.query._method === 'put' && value === undefined) return;

                    if(! value)
                        throw new Error('video can not remain empty');

                    let fileExt = ['.webm' , '.mp4' , '.flv' , '.avi'];
                    if(! fileExt.includes(path.extname(value)))
                        throw new Error('file extention is not acceptable');
                }),

            check('images')
                .custom(async (value , { req }) => {
                    if(req.query._method === 'put' && value === undefined) return;

                    if(! value)
                        throw new Error('video thumbnail can not remain empty');

                    let fileExt = ['.png' , '.jpg' , '.jpeg' , '.svg'];
                    if(! fileExt.includes(path.extname(value)))
                        throw new Error('file extention is not acceptable')
                })
        ]
    }

    
    slug(title) {
        return title.replace(/([^۰-۹آ-یa-z0-9]|-)+/g , "-")
    }
}

module.exports = new mvValidator();
```

the error I'm getting when I'm trying to update/edit

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at convertFileToField.videoHandle (test\app\http\middleware\convertFileToField.js:22:47)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (test\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (test\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:463:21
```

the error I'm getting from validator when I enter title with 2 characters instead on min of 3

```js
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
```

Comment: It seems that your last edit accidentally removed most of the information from your question. It needs to provide as much as possible for being as easily and clearly answered as possible. I undid that edit for you. Please try the intended "smaller" edit again.

Answer (score 0):

just try create a middleware like this :

videoHandle.js

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.files) {
      req.body.videos = undefined;
      req.body.images = undefined;
    } else {
      req.body.videos = (req.files.videos) ? req.files.videos[0].filename : undefined;
      req.body.images = ( req.files.images)? req.files.images[0].filename : undefined;
    }
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    const error = new HttpError("uploading failed!", 403);
    return next(error);
  }
};
```

require the middleware in the router

```
const videoHandle = require('./videoHandle');//path of videoHandler
router.post('/mvs/create',
    uploadVideo.fields([{
            name: 'videos', maxCount: 1
        }, {
            name: 'images', maxCount: 1
        }]),
    videoHandle,(req,res)=>{
   //do somtethings
    console.log(req.body)
  }
);
```

Comment: thank you for answering however, I'm getting another error, this time from mvController
`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at mvController.update (test\app\http\controllers\admin\mvController.js:81:73)`



it's here: 
`if(req.files) {
               objForUpdate.videos = this.videoPath(req.files['videos'][0]); //line 81
                objForUpdate.images = this.videoPath(req.files['images'][0]);
                
            }`

Comment: Can you change all middlewares like my answer??based on my answer you could see path of files in req.body??

Comment: should I change mvController too? would you be kind and tell me how as I'm rather new to nodejs and js

Comment: are there video and image in the request when  error is happened?

Comment: there are one image and one video and two text fields in the update form, the error happens inside the controller (I've uploaded the controller code in my question), it happens on line 81 which is the code after `//check video`, inside update middleware in Controller.

here's the link to an image of my form https://ibb.co/0BYqwgb 
and the error happens when I click edit button without re-uploading image and video

Comment: don't test your api with postman before using in frontend? send a request with postman and show me the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228545/discussion-between-sarah-moghaddam-and-mohammad-yaser-ahmadi).